# How do I echo versatile relative paths in PHP for JavaScript / CSS files?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, filepath

I have PHP files in my main project folder (/root) and a subfolder (/root/sub) under the main project folder.

Both of these PHP files have the same `<head>` sections where the same CSS and JS files are referenced, which are under /root/css and /root/js respectively. To avoid duplicating code, I took this consistent `<head>` section and put it into a PHP module called mod_head.php under /root/module. I then integrated this module using include into the PHP files under /root and /root/sub.

However, because the relative paths to the CSS and JS files are different for the PHP files under /root and /root/css and the include statement only does paths relative to the main PHP file, I'm not able to reference the CSS and JS files properly.

How do I set this up so that:

1. For PHP files under /root, the **link** and **script** tags in the `<head>` section have "JS/main.js" and "CSS/main.css" for the respective files, and
2. For PHP files under /root/sub, the **link** and **script** tags in the `<head>` section have "../JS/main.js" and "../CSS/main.css" for the respective files

I tried using **DIR** and $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], but these output absolute paths that are relevant to the server, but don't work since the search for these paths is executed on the client side.

Comment: How are you hosting the site? I assume /root is yoursite.com/? If so I'd set up a local virtual host so you can have yoursite.local pointing to yourprojectdir/root/. that way assets can have their correct urls `src="/js/foo.js"`

Comment: Right now I'm working on my Mac under /Library/WebServer/Documents but I am also hosting the live site on a Linux server on Bluehost.

Comment: then I suggest setting up a virtual host in your local development environment so you can access your site like any other domain. that way an url for the domains root (like `/js/somefile.js`) will go to the correct file and you won't have to write code just to support a badly configured development environment (which your production site has absolutely no use for)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. My problem is not knowing how to echo out a path to the CSS/JS files relative to the main PHP file not the included PHP file (which goes in the src/href values for the script/link tags) . __DIR__ only helps me get an absolute path, which doesn't work.

Comment: You use the paths the users web browser should use. So if all js files are in the project root/js/ dir then all js src should be /js/file.js . It doesnt matter what php file youre in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it in a hacky way. Knowing what the subfolder is called, I simply checked if the subfolder name is present in the getcwd() result, and if so, I echo "../CSS/main.css" and if it isn't, I echo "CSS/main.css" for the file path.